# Switch to another activity after successful Facebook login in Android App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am new to Adroid app development and started learning for about a week.
But since 3 days i am struggling with switching the activity after successful facebook login.

My questions :

1) I need to redirect to my another activity once the user is logged in.
2) I need to have their profile details like profile picture, email and name etc on the next activity frame (which will come after login).

Current State : After login, fragment stays as it is and Logout button is displayed.

My code for the fragment here :

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
public AccessTokenTracker mAccessTokenTracker;
public ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;

private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accesstoken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        Log.d("get me profile", "Name");
        //Log.d("Welcome :", profile.getName());


    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

    }
};

public LoginFragment(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    AccessTokenTracker mAccessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldtracker, AccessToken newtracker) {

        }
    };

    mAccessTokenTracker.startTracking();

    ProfileTracker mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldprofile, Profile newprofile) {
            //Log.d("New Name", "data");
        }
    };

    mProfileTracker.startTracking();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mCallback);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mAccessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

Request your kind words guys to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

For Answering your first question
1) In the `FacebookCallback:onSuccess` method you will can the method which will opens the next *Activity* needed, and in the `onCreate` of the *Fragment*, you will check if the **AccessToken** is Null, if it is null then do nothing to wait for User to press login, if it is not Null, then call the same method get open the *Activity* needed as the user is already logged in

2) you have check the Documents and permissions to get the Profile picture and name for the current logged user, and if you have questions, please write the code you use first to get User data